# PHP SQL - match() against ()

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean

I can't figure out the following code. I've been trying and searching for hours but I can't seem to find anything.

What I'm trying to do is find all words that match some criteria. In this example I'm trying to find all entries that contain the word "shoe" or shoes etc. (note the asterisk ), and that also contain "leather" or leathers etc. but also doesn't include the words trainer, boot, high heels, jacket, trainers, belt or pumps

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND MATCH (post_content,post_title,post_name) AGAINST ('"*shoe*" "*leather*" -"trainer" -"boot" -"high heels" -"jacket" -"trainers" -"belt" -"pumps" ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I can't seem to get the logic right, I seem to get results that contain just the word "Shoe(s)" but not "leather(s)" or "Leather(s) but not "shoe(s)" I've also tried the following with no success:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND MATCH (post_content,post_title,post_name) AGAINST ('+"*shoe*" +"*leather*" -"trainer" -"boot" -"high heels" -"jacket" -"trainers" -"belt" -"pumps" ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I've learnt about using the "+" and "-", but I can't figure out how to use them for the above scenario.

If someone could help point me in the right direction, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried `LIKE`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

> SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND MATCH (post_content,post_title,post_name) AGAINST (' "*shoe*" "*leather*" -"trainer" -"boot" -"high heels" -"jacket" -"trainers" -"belt" -"pumps" ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

I believe what you are looking for (using BOOLEAN MODE) is akin to:

> SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND MATCH (post_content,post_title,post_name) AGAINST (' *shoe* *leather* -trainer -boot -"high heels" -jacket -trainers -belt -pumps ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

I have removed the extraneous quotes. Asterisk(*) won't work as expected between quotes because things in quotes are taken literally. See [MySQL FullText Boolean](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for this section:

> "
>
> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".
>
> If the phrase contains no words that are in the index, the result is empty. For example, if all words are either stopwords or shorter than the minimum length of indexed words, the result is empty.

In your code -"*shoe*" and -"*leather*" will not work as expected. Removing the quotes should resolve that.